# How to have a property in a class that can deserialize into any of the two types of classes in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

I want to have a property in my class which can be of two types in .net6.

```
Class A {
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Age {get;set;}
}

Class B {
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

//I want something like below:
Class MyClass{
public <A|B> myProperty {get;set;}
}
```

myProperty can be of any type A or B from the API response. How to deserialize this into A or B? Can anybody help how to achieve this?

Comment: Depends on what you expect to do via `myProperty`. Do you need the setter? Do you expect to access anything on the returned value other than `Name`?

Comment: Yes I expect Name & Age. If Age = null then only Name.

Answer (score 0):

First, you create an interface with the properties common to both A and B:

```
interface IHasName
{ 
     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then you have your classes implement that interface:

```
class A : IHasName
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
} 
// same for class B
```

and finally you can use the interface type instead of `A|B`:

```
class MyClass
{
    public IHasName MyPropertyContainingAOrB { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: When I deserialize into the class type MyClass, I cannot access the property Age from MyPropertyContainingAOrB. How to solve this?

Comment: @HavyiaAyv: Well, `A` does not have a property Age. If you are sure that MyPropertyContainingAOrB contains a value of type B, you can cast it: `var age = ((B)myClassInstance.MyPropertyContainingAOrB).Age;`.